VBA Formatting Multiple Activex Textboxes in One Sub
I have been learning VBA to create an Excel sheet which allows people to easily and quickly grade a diagram that our students must memorize and draw.
I have placed activex textboxes which have colored borders and transparent backgrounds when empty, but turn opaque when a number is entered (textbox_change() events).
I am running into an issue where I have to make thousands of these yet I can only figure out how to implement the change one sub at a time. I have a workaround of copying to word, find and replace, then add to next sub. However, this ends up being very messy and time consuming.
Is there a way to have a single sub/function that implements formatting changes (if not empty-> font color=x, etc.) Or do I have to have an individual sub for each textbox_change() event?
Thank you for your time.
I tried looping through all textboxes on worksheet change which worked, but it checked every box every time which would be very laggy and unresponsive, so it doesnt work as a time-saving measure.

I would suggest creating a single VBA Class tied to a textbox, such that each instance of that class creates a separate object. Each of those class objects would then respond to events (textbox changes) independently. Implementing this way cuts your code down to a single class, plus the other code to create the textboxes-with-the-class. See this solution for some good information.

@PeterT 's solution is probably much better than mine but I'm not familiar with above. I have tackled this same issue by writing a "unique" sub for each textbox.
However, I've used formulas to write the sub's and then simply pasted all sub's at the same time. Example, Cell A1 = 2, Cell A2 = 2, Cell A3 = 3 etc. Then write in Cell B1 ="if textbox"&A1&" = EMPTY then" etc, and you can simply drag this formula down. Meaning it takes the same amount of time to create 10 of theses Subs as 100.

@PeterT Between looking at that link and similar ones I think this definitely is the approach I needed. However, I am struggling with adapting the examples to my textboxes; these examples all use userforms and I am not skilled enough to adapt them to activex textboxes. Thank you for the lead though, I think I can eventually get there with this.
